# Nothing appears on UITableViewController after I assign it a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7.3

I have a swift app which so far only has one view ('main view'). I wanted to add a settings page so I added a `UITableViewController` and made one button on the main view open this settings view as a Popup. So far so good. I then wanted to add custom code for the second view so I made a cocoa touch class called `settingsViewController` which inherited from `UITableViewController`, and assigned that as the 'custom class' for the settings view. Now nothing on the settings view shows up and I don't know why ?!

If I remove the custom class specification for the settings view, everything starts showing up again.

What's the issue here?

I'm using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1

When 'custom class' field for settings view is empty:

[image]

When 'custom class' field for settings view has `settingsViewController` mentioned in it:

[image]

EDIT:

Here's the entire contents of my `settingsViewController` class:

```
import UIKit

class settingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you put return 0 in your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` function? Those number defined your table view section and row. No wonder your table doesn't show anything.

Comment: Why are you returning 0 for `#ofSections` and `#ofRows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the total number of sections and rows in each section through the delegate methods.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0   // This shouldn't be zero
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0   // This shouldn't be zero
}
```

These are the data source methods. You should assign them to a specific data Source.

Example:

```
// This is the dataSource for now as an example
var dataList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1    // We have a 1D array here only
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataList.count   // Total no. of items in the array.
}
```

And, that is how you set the number of sections and rows in each section as an example. By setting them to ZERO, they will likely so an empty section and cells.

> **Try putting them something else than ZERO and see for yourself.**

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari